# Mysql cascade delete not working

Tags: mysql

In mysql, I have two tables `players` and `walls`.

I use this to create the walls table:

```
CREATE TABLE walls (id int AUTO_INCREMENT, player_id int, x int, y int, PRIMARY KEY(id), FOREIGN KEY (player_id) REFERENCES players(id) ON DELETE CASCADE);

alter table walls add unique index(x, y);
```

The column `player_id` is a foreign key to the `id` column of the `players` table.
I want it so that, if any rows gets deleted from the players table, then any rows from the walls table that have a foreign key to the deleted rows of the players table, should also get deleted from the walls table automatically using cascade delete. But when I do this, the rows in the walls table don't get deleted.

Anyone know whats wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: did you check that you're creating innodb tables? Older mysqls default to using myisam which understand-but-ignore foreign key definitions, and do not support cascades of any sort.

Comment: `show create table yourtable;`. it'll show the exact sql necessary to recreate it, and at the end of the command will be `engine=myisam` or whatever.

Comment: @MarcB, that's absolutely correct. I think it should posted as answer. what you say. marked both your comment with +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Confirm that your tables are actually using an engine which supports foreign keys, e.g. InnoDB. Older MySQLs will by default create MyISAM tables, which understand the foreign key definitions, but completely ignore them.

Simple test: `show create table yourtable;`. If the `engine=` line indicates it's a non-FK-enabled engine, there's your problem.